# Post method using retrofit not working, logcat saying its null

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to send some data to my server, it says that data was sent however when I check the website nothing happens. In the logcat it says that mView is null.
I tried different methods in order to send data to the server, but it always appears the same error.
Here is the model that is in my server:
[image]

[image]

Here are my classes

The endpoint:

```
     interface Endpoint {
@GET("ocorrenciasapi")
fun getPosts():Call<List<Ocorrencia>>

@POST("ocorrenciasapi")
@FormUrlEncoded
open fun savePost(
    @Field("dispositivo") dispositivo: String?,
    @Field("dataOcorrencia") dataOcorrencia: String?,
    @Field("latitude") latitude: String?,
    @Field("longitude") longitude: String?,
    @Field("azimute") azimute: String?,
    @Field("fotografia") fotografia: String?,
    @Field("nomeFotografia") nomeFotografia: String?,
    @Field("estado") estado: String?
): Call<Ocorrencia?>?
```

}

networkutils class:

```
  class NetworkUtils {

companion object{

    fun getRetrofitInstance(path : String) : Retrofit{

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(path)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

ocorrencia class:

```
  data class Ocorrencia (
@SerializedName("dispositivo") val dispositivo: String?,
@SerializedName("dataOcorrencia") val dataOcorrencia: String?,
@SerializedName("latitude") val latitude: String?,
@SerializedName("longitude") val longitude: String?,
@SerializedName("azimute") val azimute: String?,
@SerializedName("fotografia") val fotografia: String?,
@SerializedName("nomeFotografia") val nomeFotografia: String?,
@SerializedName("estado") val estado: String?
```

)

Here is the method that sends it:

```
   fun sendPost(){

    val retrofitClient = NetworkUtils
        .getRetrofitInstance("https://adamastor.ipt.pt/appFogos/api/")

    val endpoint = retrofitClient.create(Endpoint::class.java)
    val callback = endpoint.savePost(
        "teste1",
        "2020-06-12T12:26:48.0095273",
        "37.089940",
        "-7.800357",
        "43",
        "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7",
        "teste1Foto",
        "aceite")

    callback?.enqueue(object  : retrofit2.Callback<Ocorrencia?>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Ocorrencia?>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Ocorrencia?>, response: Response<Ocorrencia?>) {

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"A ocorrência foi enviada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }


    })

}
```

Comment: Is toast with message "A ocorrência foi enviada" shown after sending post request?

Comment: yes it is, it is shown like everything was sent right and it was recived by the server

Comment: Please add additional logs to `onResponse` method to check if response is successful: `Log.d("TEST", " isSuccessful: ${response.isSuccessful}")
    Log.d("TEST", " body: ${response.body()}")
    Log.d("TEST", " errorBody: ${response.errorBody()}")`

Comment: It gives me the this information: 06-12 17:01:36.191 12495-12495/com.example.connectionserver D/TEST:  isSuccessful: false,  06-12 17:01:36.191 12495-12495/com.example.connectionserver D/TEST:  body: null and 06-12 17:01:36.191 12495-12495/com.example.connectionserver D/TEST:  errorBody: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@7f0e484

Comment: Could you please add this log and you will see the error: `Log.d("TEST", " errorBody: ${ff.errorBody()?.string()}")`

Comment: Teresa, Did it help?

Comment: Sorry about the late response, but where should I add that line of code in my project?

Comment: Add it to `onResponse` method: `Log.d("TEST", " errorBody: ${response.errorBody()?.string()}")`